# Quotes Problem When Returning Data From PHP Script To Be Handled With JQuery/JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Here's my problem.  I have data being returned using JSON, AJAX from my php script to my page.  The data is being stored in a variable *data*

Using the variable data, I'm trying to construct a div using javascript.  However, if the data contains a single quote, it break my js code and the page script doesn't work.

example code with *data* being the variable containing data "The boy's bicycle":

```
var newrootcomment = $("<div id='container'>" + data +  "</div>");
            newrootcomment.prependTo($('#wholecontainer')).hide().fadeIn(300).slideDown(1000);
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the `json_encode` function available in PHP? Are are you treating the response as JSON? `jQuery.parseJSON(<json-string>)`.

From there you interact with it simple as an object.

```
var resp = {};
```

If you don't have jQuery, most browsers support `JSON.parseJSON()`.

Also, make sure you use double quotes for attributes.

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

This is normally how I use json_encode:

```
$resp = array(
 "foo"=>"foo_value",
 "bar"=>"bar_value",
 "foo_bar"=>array("one","two",3),
 "message"=>"AWesome"
)
return json_encode($resp)
```

Comment: Here's my code: echo echo json_encode('{ "author": "'.$author.'"}'); and client side: data = JSON.parse(data);  where data is the array of json objects passed.  Am I doing it right?

Comment: Nope. json_encode can take a well formed array. I'll post an example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for PHP - it'll return a quoted string with JSON-safe characters - it'll escape entities like `\n, \, "`. etc

**Edit**

Note that a single quote in JSON is not required to be escaped since it surrounded by double quotes.

From what you said in a comment to @jbcurtin's answer, about your PHP code being `echo json_encode('{ "author": "'.$author.'"}');` I'd say that that is one problem. You don't need to encode the entire string, only the author variable. That line should be `echo '{"author": '. json_encode($author) . '}';` instead.

Comment: your username doesn't instill confidence in me.  I'll wait for other answers :p

Comment: then how do I get the original data on clientside?  Will it still contain the /  ?